# Swagger Editor not showing multipart form request parameters

Tags: swagger, documentation-generation, openapi, swagger-editor

Haven't found an example which actually worked. What I have:

```
"beacons/add/picture": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "Beacon"
    ],
    "description": "Add Beacon Picture",
    "operationId": "addBeaconPic",
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "requestBody" : {
      "required": true,
      "content" : {
        "multipart/form-data" : {
          "schema" : {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/AddBeaconPicture"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/BaseResponse"
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "unexpected error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorModel"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the documentation, the parameters look empty, however there are multiple form parameters required like id, name etc.

Comment: You are mixing up OpenAPI 2.0 and OpenAPI 3.0 syntax that's why it doesn't work. Is your spec `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`? How is your multipart request supposed to look like - e.g. just key/value pairs, or single file upload, or an array of files, or file + JSON?

Comment: Its a mix of file upload and text body party.